# PDF a Word con codigo

Tags: c#, pdf

Buen día, he estado buscando mucho y no he podido encontrar algún código de referencia para convertir los PDF a Word, todo lo que encuentro son DLL que por lo regular son de paga (entre 500 y 100 Dolares).
Por eso quisiera saber si alguien tiene conocimiento de como puedo hacer la conversión, sea **C#** o cualquier otro lenguaje.
Saludos.

Comment: Ya probaste esta? es una librería gratuita https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-convert-PDF-to-DOCX-8d2de5ce

Comment: Gracias Omar Viñas pero ya utilice esa librería "gratuita", solo permite la conversión de 3 paginas, y posteriormente agrega una marca de agua muy grande en el documento.

Comment: Un camino mas laborioso podria ser convertir el pdf en imagenes y luego usar un OCR para leerlas en caso que necesitaras el puro texto.